# Need to build/publish WPF app that only runs from USB Flash Drive

Tags: wpf, usb-drive

I am building a small WPF application that will be distributed/sold on a USB Flash drive. The application will run from the flash drive and all data entered will be stored on the flash drive.

I have built my proof of concept but my question is how do I build the install? When I try to publish the app it creates the normal setup.exe and the needed manifest files. The setup appears to check for prereqs (framework and such) then installs a startup icon. But it truly installs the program on the hard drive of the computer, which is not what I want.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to deploy/build/publish the application to not install but run from the USB Flash drive?

Comment: I agree with Daniel.  I don't think you are going to get around that .NET framework must be installed.  You can run the .exe directly off the flash drive but I don't think there is such a thing as a self contained .NET.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to run on machines that don't already have the .NET framework (3.5 SP1 would probably be the minimum) then there is no way to avoid a big installation step that effects the target machine permanently.

Comment: There are build options that allow you to remove the checks for the pre-reqs. Which would make for either a bad instal if the user didn't have those requirements or make the install a manual process by providing the MSI files. But regardless, can you run it from the flash drive? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Just compile and run the .exe that is created in the debug directory.   I run .NET .exe from network drives all the time.  If the .NET framework is not installed then it will fail.

Comment: Well. Snap, Krackle and Cocoa Krispies. That works. I will probably build something on the front end to check for prereqs but in whole, that works. Thanks Balam.

Comment: @Chris - traditionally you would at least upvote this answer, maybe even accept it!